# Media Querys working in desktop browsers, but not mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

Works fine in any of the main 5 up to date browsers, but not on any mobile device, have no idea why.

This is my code

```
/* Desktop */
@import url("desktop.css");

/* Small Phone */
@import url("smallMobile.css") only screen and (max-width:320px);

/* Large Phone and small Tablet */
@import url("largeMobile-smallTablet.css") only screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-width:600px);
```

/* Tablet and small Desktop*/
@import url("tablet-smallDesktop.css") only screen and (min-width:601px) and (max-width:1120px);

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@media only screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-width:600px) {
  @import url("largeMobile-smallTablet.css");
}
```

or

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width:321px) and (max-device-width:600px) {
  @import url("largeMobile-smallTablet.css");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `device-width` and make sure you know which phones you want to target; newer iPhones have different `device-pixel-ratio` values which alter the `device-width`

Here are the media queries for different iPhones (check out more common dimensions here, https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/):

```
/* ----------- iPhone 4 and 4S ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}


/* ----------- iPhone 5 and 5S ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* ----------- iPhone 6 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 

}


/* ----------- iPhone 6+ ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { 

}
```

And for iPads:

```
/* ----------- iPad 1 and 2 ----------- */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* ----------- iPad 3 and 4 ----------- */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}
```